# silent and non-interactive installation of a package in Solaris using pkgadd and admin file

Tags: software-installation, package-management, solaris

The command am giving is:

```
pkgadd -a admin file -d absolutepathofpackage
```

Then, its showing the below error

> ```
> The following packages are available:
> 1  Packagename      BigFix Agent
>                   (sparc) 9.2.8.74
>
> Select package(s) you wish to process (or 'all' to process
> all packages). (default: all) [?,??,q]: all
> ```

How to get this step included during silent installation?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/a/150050/283415  Your command is not telling `pkgadd` *which* package(s) in the stream to install.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pkgadd -n ...` to install a package in non-interactive mode.

More information can be found in `man pkgadd`

Comment: Already did that. But, it still asks. From man pages,
     -n              Installation occurs in non-interactive mode.
                     Suppress  output  of  the  list of installed
                     files. The default mode is interactive.                                              which means, it just supresses the output files

Comment: does `yes all|pkgadd ...` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a "admin" file better called "response file"

for example I use this

```
mail=
instance=overwrite
partial=quit
runlevel=quit
idepend=quit
rdepend=quit
space=quit
setuid=nocheck
conflict=quit
action=nocheck
basedir=default
```

Before use it

```
man -s4 admin
```

And check if every line meet your requirements

Then install with this command

```
pkgadd -a file.response -n -d /path/pkg.pkg
```

or

```
yes all|pkgadd -a file.response -d /path/pkg.pkg
```

Comment: "yes all | pkgadd..." did not work for me, I had to use "yes | pkgadd..."